# What is meant by the phrase "Charlie Brown management"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context

Recently I came to hear the term "Charlie Brown management" in a news [article](http://www.businessweek.com/news/2011-05-26/greenlight-s-einhorn-says-microsoft-should-replace-steve-ballmer.html). I tried searching the net on this term, but didn't get anything useful. Please help me to decipher this idiom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Charlie Brown" refers to the character in the cartoon strip *Peanuts*.

Charlie Brown always failed in every thing he does.

The President of the company was stating how bad management was.

Answer (score 2):

The article defines it for you, if you read it.

> Still, Ballmer isn’t taking advantage of Microsoft’s opportunities, Einhorn said. 
>   In his criticism, he likened Ballmer to Charlie Brown, a perpetual loser in baseball,
>   football and other pursuits. The cartoon character’s signature lament is, “Good grief!”

I'm assuming that you just read the first paragraph. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: That sentence just compares Ballmer to Charlie Brown. It's one thing to compare the two (which isn't that bad a comparison, on a lot of levels) but 'Charlie Brown management' implies there is something about how the company is being managed that's Charlie Brown-like. It's not a very good metaphor.

Comment: Charlie Brown was (is? surely he is immortal) the manager of a baseball team which never won a game, partly but not entirely because of his incompetence.  I feel a management advice best-seller coming on...